# How can I associate text box with radio button group

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I am trying to prepare a simple form. My form has 3 radio buttons and 1 text/numeric input box.
This is supposed work like this, user can choose to click on radio 1,2 or 3 that is alright, but if the user chooses to click radio 4, it reveals a text box where user can input text. So saying this simple, the user input from radio 1 or 2 or 3 or text box only is collected. But i am not able to do this....phew....and i can collect user input upon form submission but don't have any idea how to restrict user only to choose 1 option out of these 4.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Present</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body"><input class="form-control input-lg text-left" name="1" id="1" type="text"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Absent</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body"><input type="radio" id="Absent" name="jan1" value="Absent"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Holiday</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body"><input type="radio" id="Holiday" name="jan1" value="Holiday"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Where are button 4 and the text box in your HTML?

Comment: Add click event listeners to the radio buttons. The listener for button 4 should show the text box. The listener for the other 3 buttons should hide the text box.